# Report Field Should Show "N/A" Based on Separate Field

Tags: ms-access, report, conditional-formatting

I have the following report showing:

``````````````````````````````
F1    |    F2    |    F3    |
`````````````````````````````
TRUE  |   TRUE   |  FALSE   |
TRUE  |   FALSE  |  FALSE   |
FALSE |   N/A    |  N/A     |
``````````````````````````````

As you can see, I would like to display fields F2 and F3 only when F1 is true. F1 is a false, F2 and F3 should display "N/A" regardless of their real value.

How might I do this? I've tried

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
If (Me.F1 = false) Then
    Me.F2.Visible = False
    Me.F3.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

But this does not change the value to the text (only removes the field, which I could settle on), but it also removes it for ALL fields; not just the one in that row. How else can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to rename the control from say, F2 to txtF2 and then set the control source to a function.

```
=iif(F1=true,F2,"N/A")
```

Regarding setting visibility, you have to put in both sides:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)

If (Me.F1 = false) Then
    Me.F2.Visible = False
    Me.F3.Visible = False
Else
    Me.F2.Visible = True
    Me.F3.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Or more simply:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
Me.F2.Visible = Me.F1
Me.F3.Visible = Me.F1
```

Comment: Crap, tried that. Never thought to change the name of the control to avoid the circular reference...

Comment: Yep. That used to get me every last time.

Comment: Thanks again! Good, complete answer. Worked.